# Unable to publish azure webjob using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to publish webjob through powershell.

I followed below article

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-a-WebJob-using-PowerShell-ARM-Cmdlets

I have used script in Azure Release Def with Azure Powershell task.

I'm getting error

> Missing Content-Disposition header.

at below script

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $Header -Method put -InFile "<Complete path of the file>\
<filename>.zip" -ContentType 'application/zip'
```

I'm already including `Content-Disposition` in Header as below, but still getting error.

```
$Header = @{
'Content-Disposition'='attachment; attachment; filename=Copy.zip'
'Authorization'=$accessToken
        }
```

How to resolve it.

Comment: I ran the script from the referenced doc and wasn't able to replicate the issue. Did you make any changes other than filling in the details for your app and file location?

Comment: Could you please provide your script?